# Detect Red Line in Html

Tags: html, beautifulsoup, urllib

In this table, there is red line. 
http://www.data.jma.go.jp/obd/stats/etrn/view/monthly_s3_en.php?block_no=47830&view=1

How can I know if there is red line or not in the table from the html?

```
url = "http://www.data.jma.go.jp/obd/stats/etrn/view/monthly_s3_en.php?block_no=47830&view=1"

html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
table = soup.select_one("table.data2_s")
print table
```

how to detect red line from the program?

This table do not have red line.
http://www.data.jma.go.jp/obd/stats/etrn/view/monthly_s3_en.php?block_no=47831&view=1

I wanted to read both urls above, and test if there is red line or not using the program.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just [edit] the question and add the relevant parts of your code into it, because without that we cannot help. Also please see **[ask]**.

Comment: There is no attempt at "red line detection" in the few lines of code that you included. You need to show your own efforts, SO is not a write-my-code-for-me service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class-names of the td-s would be a good indicator. Lined td-s have a different class than non-lined. You could check for existence of the class "data_1t_0_0_0" for example.

Comment: So, can I use `if 'data_1t_0_0_0' not in table: print 'OK'`?

Comment: There are other classes for border-left, right, top etc. so you'd need to check those, too.

Comment: If there is red line somewhere in the table, i should skip that url. So, how can i write logic in the program?

Comment: You'll need to parse the contents of the HTML first. There's no way of telling soley from the URL if that's what you mean.

Comment: yes, i need to parse the contents of the HTML first. But, then how to test if 'data_1t_0_0_0' is in table?

Comment: I don't know which language you are using for parsing, but I'd search for this string line by line, and if it's found somewhere I know there's a red line.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the iframe like then you could read your iframe content like this:

```
$('#frame').load(function () {
setTimeout(function () {
    alert($('#frame').contents().find('.data_1t_0_0_1l').length);
}, 2000);
```

});